# How to connecting and communicating with Bluetooth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I've been searching Bluetooth BLE usage with Flutter but it seems there are only a few plugins and they've some issues. I don't want to use any plugin because I only need to read a QR code, Get MACaddress and let Flutter connect to a hidden Bluetooth device with a static password.

1- Ask Bluetooth permission:

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

iOS In the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need BLE permission</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need BLE permission</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Location permission</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Location permission</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need Location permission</string>
```

2- Set Bluetooth enable,
3- Check if the Bluetooth device "$MACadress" reachable,
4- Connect and send a 25byte hex array.

**Is there any pluginless way to do this with Flutter?**
**If not then which way should I follow?**

Comment: flutter_blue [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)
flutter_bluetooth_serial [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)

Answer (score 0):

No. Flutter itself without plugins is pretty limited. There is no Bluetooth API built in.

That's the downsides of using any "cross platform" app maker system - they often lack desired features, making it more complicated to do "native" stuff than if you just did a "native" app to start with. Unless someone has already done the hard work and written good enough bindings

Anyway, on iOS you can't connect to a BLE device only using its device address, since iOS hides the address.

Comment: flutter_blue plugin only supports BLE devices. flutter_serial plugin only support Android, I'm stuck at this point what should I do?

Comment: Well first of all iOS doesn't support normal apps (non mfi-certified) to use Bluetooth Classic. To answer your question "what should I do" - you haven't really explained what you want to achieve. You should first read through the restrictions the different platforms have. And if you really want to use Flutter but cannot find any plugin you like, then write your own plugin.